# RSA encryption theory - modulo theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, cryptography

I'm a bit mathematically challenged and have been working on the RSA cipher (good start). I can find the public and private keys and know how to work do modulo operations on a calculator. The problem is that I can't do them when the numbers get to high. For example say I have:

$$10^{541} \bmod{2923} = C$$
The numbers involved here become very large and don't display fully on a calculator, if it can even handle the numbers (mine is crap). What I am wondering is if there is a better method to work out the ciphertext or plaintext that will work for largish numbers.

N.B. I'm not a mathematician, I'm in computing but was told my question would be better posed here.

Comment: You don't really do this kind of calculation by hand. If you do, I still think this is algorithmic question more than a mathematical one and belongs in cs.se or stackoverflow.

Comment: You should not compute $10^{541}$ ever. One simple way to keep numbers small is to multiply by $10$ each time, and reduce by $2923$ after each multiplication. More advanced techniques include square-and-multiply.

Answer (score 4):

You should familiarize yourself with [the square and multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). That way you never need to multiply together numbers larger than the modulus (here 2923).

The ideas is crudely that you first calculate remainders $x_k$ of $10^{2^k}$ modulo $2923$ for as high $k$ as needede by repeated squaring:
$$
10^2\equiv 100\pmod{2923},
$$
$$
10^4=(10^2)^2=10000\equiv1231\pmod{2923},
$$
(because $10000=8769+1231=3\cdot2923+1231)$,
$$
10^8=(10^4)^2\equiv1231^2\equiv x_3 \pmod{2923},
$$
(can't be bothered to compute $x_3$ now, sorry)
$$
10^{16}=(10^8)^2\equiv x_3^2\equiv x_4\pmod{2923}, 
$$
and so on all the way up to
$$
10^{512}=(10^{256})^2\equiv x_8^2\equiv x_9\pmod{2923}.
$$
At this point you know integers $x_k,k=0,1,2,\ldots,9$ such that
$0\le x_k<2923$ and $10^{2^k}\equiv x_k\pmod{2923}$. You had to calculate the squares of nine integers (all smaller than $2923$) and the remainders of those squares. Then you can finish off by multiplying a chosen selection of those numbers and the remainde of that product:
$$
10^{541}=10^{512+16+8+4+1}=10^{512}\cdot10^{16}\cdot10^8\cdot10^4\cdot10
\equiv x_9x_4x_3x_2x_0.
$$

The usual description of square and multiply organizes the calculations a bit more efficiently (so that you don't have to store so many intermediate results), but the general idea is as above.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) when I want to check calculations like that quickly, for example you would enter `10^541 mod 2923` into the search bar to calculate $C=2748$

The square and multiply method mentioned in Jyrki Lahtonen's answer is good to implement if you are writing this as code though athough generally languages have a built in method for it, for example in Python it would be `C = pow(10, 541, 2923)`